# Formula to find out how many active days in a month

Tags: google-sheets, formula, pivot-table

I am trying to get a formula to calculate the number of my active days in a month. I make many transactions per day but I only want to know how many days I have been active for. Below is an example of my data:

[image: https://gyazo.com/c94d0743ded87c311ae600a1de0aeb7d]

Comment: removed, newbie to forum

Comment: do you want to count distinct dates in a column? what if there is more than one month?

Comment: yeah, count distinct dates in one month, I have a sheet for every month so would copy formula over for each month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=countunique(A2:A1000)
```

If you want to see which dates, I'd suggest a pivot table with `Date` for Rows and Values as Date with Summarise by: COUNTUNIQUE.

Comment: Many Thanks, much appreciated. Added that to my limited arsenal of knowledge :)